# Jquery move by whole section when user tries to scroll

Tags: jquery

I created this code that should move the page by a whole section when the user tries to scroll.

```
$(window).on("scroll", function fff(event) {
    var section;
    $('.section_class').each(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > ($(this).offset()['top'])) {
            section = $(this).next();
        }
    });
    $(window).off("scroll");
    $(window).scrollTo(section, {
        duration: 1000,
        done: function () {
            $(window).on("scroll", fff(event));
        }
    });
```

It should work like this: on scroll, each loop fires and checks what section user currently sees. Then the page should scroll to the next one (using jquery scrollTo plugin). However this works only once, then it just blocks itself.

I suspect that when the `scrollTo` animation starts, another scroll event fires and tries scroll to the CURRENT section. To avoid that I tried to disable the event right before the animation starts and enable it again when it finishes, but that did not help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you want is a snapping behaviour. There are many jQuery plugins already functional that you can use, for example:

- http://wtm.github.io/jquery.snapscroll/
- http://guidobouman.github.io/jquery-panelsnap/

Comment: Thanks for these iinks. but it also bugs me why my code is broken.

Comment: I think the problem is due to the fff function scope. See here for a working example: https://jsbin.com/dikufaqoti/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to use full screen sections I would recommend you to go for [fullpage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/).

You can use the option `autoScrolling:false` to create a normal scrolling website and then `fitToSection:true` (active by default) to fit to the section taking more space in your screeen.

[Demo here](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/normalScroll.html).

You can configure the fit delay with the option `fitToSectionDelay`.